# Echoing the right array position multiple times

Tags: php, arrays, loops, if-statement

I've completed this exercise with code below and it works but I reckon that there is a better way, without 5xif loops...Perhaps it can be done with foreach...

```
  `<?php 

  if (in_array($number, $arr)!= TRUE) {
         echo "<br/>".$number." is not in the array";
  }
  // foreach($arr as $number1) {
   //  if ($number==$number1) {
   //      echo "<br/>".$number." is in slot ".array_search($number,$arr);
    // }
  //}
  if ($number==$arr[0]) {
     echo "<br/>".$number." is in slot 0";
  }
  if ($number==$arr[1]) {
     echo "<br/>".$number." is in slot 1";
  }
  if ($number==$arr[2]) {
     echo "<br/>".$number." is in slot 2";
  }
  if ($number==$arr[3]) {
     echo "<br/>".$number." is in slot 3";
  }
  if ($number==$arr[4]) {
     echo "<br/>".$number." is in slot 4";
  }


  exit;
  ?>`
```

Comment: Your commented code is a good start.  Why don't you try it out?

Comment: you don't need to exit at the end of a PHP script. That's already what PHP does. Also, that `for` loop looks great, but if you want both the value and the index, the syntax is `foreach($arr as $key=>$value)`. It looks like you've got a good enough grasp to take it from there.

Comment: @brycem I know that it works but I wanted to know is there a little less robust solution ;)

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans Thanks ;) I will try to make something out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. This also works perfectly.

```
 foreach($arr as $key => $number1) {
    if ($number==$number1) {
         echo "<br/>".$number." is in slot ".$key;
    }
  }
```